# What Java Collection to use in this case?

Tags: java, android, collections

I am Java novice and am trying to figure out what Java collection to use to flatten values I get from JSON into a Java collection but don't know which collection to use.  Here is what I am getting from JSON:

user: Tim
product: Beer

user: Tim
product: Bread

user: Tim
product: Milk

user: Tim
product: Soap

user: Michael
product: Soap

user: Michael
product: Coffee

user: Michael
product: Car

user: Wayne
product: Bread

user: Wayne
product: Soap

As you can see my users have following products:
Tim: Beer, Bread, Milk, Soap
Michael: Soap, Coffee, Car
Wayne: Bread, Soap

What would be best collection to use to store these so I can determine all products held by one user?

For example, by providing Key=Michael, I will get Soap, Coffee, Car.

Much appreciated,

Comment: It really depends on how you want to implement this. You have Lists, Maps, Heaps, Trees, Graphs...

Comment: Personally, I would use a `HashMap<String, ArrayList<String>>`, but it really depends on how you need to access the data.  Another option would be a 'matrix' (2d array) of booleans, where so each row is a person and each column is a product.  This is really too broad of a question for this, I'm afraid.

Comment: Thanks soong, I thought HashMap does not allow duplicate keys??  Would you mind providing bit more detail how to implement HashMap<String, ArrayList<String>>?  Much appreciated

Comment: Your `ArrayList<String>` would contain the `Strings` "Beer", "Bread", "Milk", etc. Then key "Tim" would map to this list.

Comment: If the users are unique simply use HashMap<String, ArrayList<String>>

Comment: please accept/upvote an answer if you found helpful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depends on your usecase for the data. Seems like a Map would be a good choice.

Comment: Thanks Shreyas, but I ghouth HashMap does not allow dupllicate keys

Comment: Yes. The hashmap will have key as the user and value as an ArrayList of products `HashMap<String,ArrayList<String>>`

Answer (score 4):

I would use a Multimap since one person may have multiple products.

You can find a fairly straightforward example at: http://www.leveluplunch.com/java/examples/guava-multimap-example/

so you may end up with something like this:

```
Multimap<String,String> myMap = new Multimap<>();
myMap.put("Tim", "Beer");
myMap.put("Tim", "Bread");
myMap.put("Tim", "Milk");
```

then to see what products are associated with Tim:

```
List<String> products = myMap.get("Tim");
for(String product: products){
    System.out.println(product);
}
```

this would print

```
Beer
Bread
Milk
```